# webpage css overrides ckeditor 3 style

Tags: css, ckeditor, fckeditor

I've got a page where I load screen.css which contains an **evil** rule, which for various reasons I cannot remove or modify:

```
a {
    background: red !important;
}
```

I use [CKEditor 3.x](http://ckeditor.com/) on the same page and the problem is that, no matter which style I choose (v2, kama, office2003), the buttons of the editor look red.

FCKeditor 2.x didn't have an issue with this because it was creating an iframe to host the whole editor instance. Thus the evil css snippet didn't even exist in its page.

The new CKEditor 3.x though uses divs and tables to host the editor wrapper and buttons and then an iframe just for the rich textarea content.

Any solutions for this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2.x style wrapper iframe (which would by default solve this problem) [was removed for performance reasons and is not possible via an option but only if I implement it my self](http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=20360).

What I did to overcome this problem was to modify the css files of the "kama" skin, adding !important rules to where I needed them. I don't feel this is an acceptable solution though.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, fun.

[Specificity](http://htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/) to the rescue.

Create a new stylesheet that overrides that a { color: red !important} }. Make it something that suits you, and make sure that it ALWAYS gets loaded after your evil style sheet and before the CKEditor sheet. For example:

```
a { color: lemonchiffon !important; }
```

But please read the link...specficity is fairly specific.

Comment: The evil css snippet was an example. Imagine that there are many evil rules and also each one of those (e.g padding: 0 !important)  overrides many different CKEditor rules which I cannot easily replicate, unless I completely rewrite the skin. I was looking for a way to inject CKEditor within an iframe.

Comment: +1 for mentioning usage of NEW STYLESHEET. When using the open source licensed version, and having CKEditor integrated into a commercial website, then this is the correct and legal option for dealing with visual discrepancies (that way CKEdtior's own stylesheets will remain intact), and the opensource license will not be violated.