# CKEditor 3: Table style gets overwritten

Tags: css, ckeditor, css-tables

I just installed CKEditor 3.0. Everything works fine, except the style of the editor. Because in this newest version the WYSIWYG buttons are put on the website (instead in a frame), my stylesheet overwrites the CKEditor buttons. My stylesheet contains te following:

```
.block table tr td,
.block table tr th {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: normal;
    text-align: left;
}
```

But since CKEditor uses tables, they get pretty messed up. What to do?

(This question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864890/webpage-css-overrides-ckeditor-3-style) one, but I don't think the answer given on that page is the correct answer. After all, it should be possible to solve this problem without hacking in CKEditor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me. Came up with an easy solution, just changing my stylesheet to:

```
.block > table
```

So that the rule only applies to the first table. Again, this is still not the correct way of doing this. So other answers are still welcome!